# What is the fate of obsolete comments after an answer is edited?

Tags: discussion, comments

Recently I asked a question and an answer had a false information. So I commented that the information is wrong, after tha the answer owner edited his answer and now my comment became irrelevant to the answer and it looks like to me that I'm trying to show off by giving additional info which is irrelevant to the answer and to the question.

I don't want to delete it as it was once correcting a false information and it is possible, there are also other people knowing that wrong. **What should I do with my comment ?**

I could't find any duplicate but I presume that this is a common problem.

**EDIT**: I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 14):

> I don't want to delete it as it was once correcting a false information

But that information was corrected now. The comment serves no more use.

Delete it.

---

Side note: comments have always been meant as temporary - if they contain important information that should be rolled into the post, as which point they served their purpose. Comments that don't serve this role should are usually also just noise and can go.

Answer (score 10):

Delete your comment once it's no longer relevant. Comments are meant to be temporary, and once they've served their purpose - in this case, prompting the poster of the answer to correct their information - there's no reason for them to stick around. In fact, they tend to become distracting.

For completeness, I will say that you're not *required* to do this. There's no rule that says you have to delete comments when they've served their purpose. But if you do it, you're helping keep the site clean.